# Optimizing a function that returns all combinations of an array's elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, performance

I am trying to optimize this function that I found online.

Example input: `[1, 2, 3]`
Example output: `[[1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`

Here's the code:

```
const combinations = arr => {
  let parentValue = [];
  let cursor = 0;

  for (const parentThis of arr) {
    const value = [[parentThis]];
    for (const thiss of parentValue) {
      value.push(thiss.concat([parentThis]));
    }
    parentValue = parentValue.concat(value);
  }
  return parentValue;
};
```

(the variable names are weird because I'm running this as a MongoDB aggregation)

Running this 10k times on an array of 10 elements takes about 23 seconds. How can I make it run faster? I am open to some tradeoffs.

An obvious improvement I found is to decrease the amount of elements. Running it 10k times on an array of 9 elements takes 9 seconds.

I suspect another improvement would be to reject some outputs before they are generated (single-element combinations and the all-elements combination might not be too useful), but I can't figure out how to put this into code.

I tried to improve by removing the first iteration (supplying `[arr[0]]` as the `initialValue` and starting the outer for loop from the second element) but it doesn't seem to make a significant difference.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. This question possibly belongs at codereview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About 1 second for 10k times on an array of 10 elements.

```js
function powerset(A){
  const n = A.length;
  const numSets = (1 << n) - 1;
  const result = new Array(numSets);

  for (let k=1; k<=numSets; k++){
    const set = [];
    result[k - 1] = set;
    let temp = k;
    let i = 0;
    while (temp){
      if (temp & 1)
        set.push(A[i]);
      temp >>= 1;
      i += 1;
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}


var A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var start = new Date;
for (let i=0; i<10000; i++)
  var t = powerset(A);
console.log((new Date - start) / 1000);
```

As noted by georg in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67440629/optimizing-a-function-that-returns-all-combinations-of-an-arrays-elements#comment119207259_67441823) under this answer, the line, `const result = new Array(numSets);` can be replaced with `const result = [];` and the assignment to `result.push(set);` in order to possibly see further improvement in efficiency. (Tested on node with array size 15-20.)

Comment: @BuğraGündüz it uses iteration rather than recursion, and sets up the result array in advance rather than pushing to it, although I'm not sure the latter matters that much.

Comment: you're the best.

Comment: v8 doesn't like preallocations, so `result = []` and `result.push` will perform better.

Comment: @georg it doesn't seem to in whatever runs the snippet in this answer. Just tested. I welcome demonstrations showing otherwise

Comment: from my understanding, there are different rules for "small" and "large" arrays. I tested with N=20, which I guess qualifies as large.

Comment: @georg I tested with the "push" idea with array length 15 and 20 on this webpage with less repetitions given the result size. They both took longer than the current implementation. As I said, I welcome demonstrations showing otherwise.

Comment: I tested in node. `push` is slightly but consistently better than pre-alloc for N >= 15.

Comment: @georg I was able to confirm your improvement on node. Thanks!

Comment: @georg I added a note about this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple push could speed the code a bit.

```
// parentValue = parentValue.concat(value);
parentValue.push(...value);
```